# Split the entries in dataframe

Tags: pandas

here is my sample data:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Name':['A,B','C','D','E,F,G']
              ,'Age':[4,6,8,9]})
```

My expected output is to split the entries if there are more than one names.

```
pd.DataFrame({'Name':['A','B','C','D','E','F','G']
              ,'Age':[4,4,6,8,9,9,9]})
```

I can only split the name but I don't now how to make it duplicated entries.
For first row, there are A,B under the Name, so I want to make it into two separate rows, A and B both are aged 4. Similarly, E,F,G are all aged at 9, so I want to convert this row into three rows with same age at 9.

```
df['Name'].apply(lambda x : x.split(','))
```

Comment: `The output data is self-explaining:` Why does 4 get duplicated twice, 6 and 8 duplicated once, and 9 gets duplicated three times?

Comment: BTW, this is simpler: `df['Name'].str.split(',')`

Comment: @NickODell They just want to `explode`. Maybe you misread it because the code style was really dense. I edited to improve it though they just reverted it by accident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine `df.set_index` + `str.split` + `explode`:

```
df.set_index('Age')['Name'].str.split(',').explode().reset_index()
```

---

```
   Age Name
0    4    A
1    4    B
2    6    C
3    8    D
4    9    E
5    9    F
6    9    G
```

Comment: Why set and reset the index? You can just `.explode('Name')`.

Comment: @wjandrea, you will get nothing with `df.explode('Name')`

Comment: You'd just need to do the split differently, e.g. `df.assign(Name=df['Name'].str.split(',')).explode('Name')`

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution:

```
df1['New Name'] = df1['Name'].str.split(',')

df1 = df1.explode("New Name")

df1.drop(columns='Name')
```